# What is the real advantage of using a UUID instead of an auto-incremented element?

Tags: uuid, distributed-databases

I've been looking at resources to understand UUIDs. I now understand what they are, but I still don't really see where they are truly useful.

Most of the information I've found revolves around the idea of a distributed system: you get almost truly unique id's automatically generated and so on all the distributed systems you shouldn't expect to see an id twice.

But why do you want that? what is the issue if two different databases have the same id? Is this only useful if you want to collect all the data from all databases and have them be unique?

Comment: "Is this only useful if you want to collect all the data from all databases and have them be unique?" That happens more often than you think.

Comment: There may also be security benefits to using UUIDs. If you are intending to expose the ID through an API or web app, UUIDs make it harder to brute force random records/documents—however this is less important in a well architected secure system.

Comment: @NG235 I see that's also a good point.

Comment: @RonJohn . I'm a junior dev so I don't have too much experience the only thing I can think of is for some kind of analytics but even then why does unique id matter. It doesn't feel like a huge gain in the general case considering the potential performance loss when indexing.

Comment: You also want global uniqueness in federated, and distributed systems: IOT sensors, for example, feeding a central database.

Answer (score 0):

> what is the issue if two different databases have the same id?

Picture a distributed application and database system that allowed you to place `Orders` for certain `Products`, like the Amazon mobile app. Let's pretend the app allowed offline functionality for when people had bad cell service, such as being able to place an `Order` offline. And then the next time they're online, that `Order` gets synced from the local database on their mobile device to the central database on Amazon's servers.

If the app was designed to use an auto-increment column as the key, let's call it `OrderId`, that got generated locally when the device was offline, it would be possible for two different people to generate the same `OrderId` for two completely different and unrelated `Orders`. Hopefully that's clear how that's a problem when they go to sync to the centralized database on Amazon's servers.

A `GUID` is a decent solution to this problem, since the chance of collisions (the same value being generated twice globally) is relatively low.

---

Of course there are other solutions than using `GUID`s such as error handling the collisions of two auto-increment `ID`s. But that may require more thought and work than using a `GUID`. But there are alternative solutions, which come down to preference, all things considered.

Comment: I understand the solution about being able to readily create id's without having to reach the database. but people seem to be suggesting that the prominent use-case for UUID is for distributed systems. I've seen videos & articles and stackoverflow answers with the same narrative. so I'm looking for an example where the UUID is actually a solution for a  problem that a distributed system would have. the only thing I can think of is reading everything from all databases.

Comment: @masonCherry *I'm looking for an example where the UUID is actually a solution for a problem that a distributed system would have*" - See: "*it would be possible for two different people to generate the same `OrderId` for two completely different and unrelated `Orders`*", with the auto-increment column. This would result in Amazon's centralized database to have 2 unrelated `Orders` with the same `OrderId`. Now when someone looks up their `Order` they'll see both their `Order` and the other person's `Order` that has the same ID, among other data integrity issues. GUIDs helps solve this problem.

Comment: _they'll see both their `Order` and the other person's `Order`_.  hmm I see . I think I was in the mindset that different servers were storing different information. I wasn't thinking of the idea that two servers would store the same information. I think this clears up my misconception

Comment: @masonCherry No prob. In my distributed system example the `Orders` originate from two different databases, one on each user's phone (for example). But then they need to eventually be synced to a single database on Amazon's servers, so Amazon can process the `Orders` and ship out the goods to the users. That is where collisions of auto-increment fields are a problem that `GUID`s are able to solve (for the most part). This is an overly simplified example of course, but you get the picture. See [my answer here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/321468/150011) for other key collision solutions too.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using a distributed DB which might have data loads on multiple nodes, GUID might be a good idea for many considerations:

- Scalability and Performance (incremental ID is centralized and asking for a new ID and checking the sequence and the last ID might consume resources)
- Sharding (Using an incremental ID might cause hotspot nodes which might be accessed more than others which is against the distributed principle)